# Windows 10 UWP App Data Not Readable When Plugged in Externally

Tags: windows-10, minecraft, uwp

I recently rebuilt my computer, including replacing the main SSD. I went with a fresh install of Windows 10 on the a SSD, with the old SSD plugged into a USB-C enclosure so that I can copy over whatever data I need.

I went to copy over the save data from the UWP version of Minecraft for Windows (Minecraft Bedrock). This is a UWP app, not to be confused with the Java version.

On my new Windows install, and in the guides online, my saved files are store in AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState. When I open up the parent directory, Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe, for the specific user profile on the external drive that I want to copy the save files from, all of the sub-folders appear as shortcuts. When I double click them they all fail to open with a "...path... unavailable" error.

My theory is that these files are actually stored in some other kind of storage location and I just need to know where to go looking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_   ....  This is a heavily secured location and you will not likely be to access it from an external location.  Locally copy the data to a neutral location and then you will be able to access it.

Comment: I tried using psexec to launch Powershell as the NT System account, but the directory was still not "available". Also, I'm not sure I have a way to boot off the old SSD anymore in order to copy it to a "neutral" location.

Comment: Does your local computer work?  Use that to get to the location you need.

Comment: “My theory is that these files are actually stored in some other kind of storage location” - They are not